# Как определить нажатие одной формы из нескольких, но при этом использовать 1 функцию(общую для всех форм)

Tags: javascript, html

Как определить нажатие и запустить функцию но при этом использовать одну функцию для множество повторяющихся форм. Сейчас поймете о чем я.

Вот есть такая  форма. На странице может быть таких несколько в зависимости от количество строк В БД (не суть).

```
<div>
    <textarea id="comment_menu"></textarea> 
    <p id="submit-kom" iid="x">Отправить</p>                                        
</div>
```

А вот скрип определяющий нажатия и запускает функцию

```
$('#submit-kom').click(function(){

        var comment = $("#comment_menu").val();
        var iid = $("#submit_kom").attr("iid");

        if (comment != ""){
            comment_menu = '1';
            $("#comment_menu").css("borderColor","#DBDBDB");
        }else{
            comment_menu = '0';
            $("#comment_menu").css("borderColor","#FDB6B6");
        }             

        if ( comment == '1'){
            $("#submit-kom").hide();

            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../xxx/xxx.php",
            data: "id="+iid+"&comment="+comments,
            dataType: "html",
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
            if (data == 'yes'){
                $("#submit-kom").show();
            }
            }
            });  
        }         
    });
```

Проблема в том что на странице присутствует не одна кнопка `оправить` с `id="submit-kom"` и поэтому  функция не срабатывать по нажатию на одну из кнопок. Как сделать чтобы все работало? может через `onclick` или что-то похожее, надо чтобы `js` определял что нажата кнопка `отправить` но с определенным `индексом` или `id`

Comment: function (e){
   var currentClick = e.target.attr(id);
}
почитай https://learn.javascript.ru/obtaining-event-object. Плюс id уникальная штука и на странице доступна всего лишь один раз, попросту навешивай на кнопки атрибуты и отлавливай атрибут e.target и все будет красиво

Comment: @Lieutenant Jim Dangle , спасибо, сейчас все почитаю и попробую что-нибудь сделать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не используйте повторяющиеся `id`, а используйте повторяющиеся классы.

(Откуда берется переменная `comments`?)

```
<form>
  <div>
    <textarea class=".comment_menu"></textarea> 
    <p class=".submit-kom" iid="x">Отправить</p>                                        
  </div>
</form>


$('.submit-kom').click(function() {

    var commentMenu = $(this).closest("form).find(".comment_menu");
    var comment = commentMenu.val();
    var iid = $(this).attr("iid");
    var comment_menu;

    if (comment != "") {
        comment_menu = '1';
        commentMenu.css("borderColor","#DBDBDB");
    } else {
        comment_menu = '0';
        commentMenu.css("borderColor","#FDB6B6");
    }             

    if ( comment_menu == '1') {
        $(this).hide();

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "../xxx/xxx.php",
          data: { id: iid, comment: comment },
          dataType: "text",
          cache: false,
          success: (function(data) {
            if (data == 'yes'){
              $(this).show();
            }
          }).bind(this)
        });  
    }         
});
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, сейчас все попробую

Comment: `comments` изначально брался из `<textarea id="comment_menu" ></textarea> `

Comment: что-то особо ничего не происходит после нажатия

Comment: здравствуйте, я разобрался в коде и все заработало, большое вам спасибо. Не подскажите еще как  правильно добавить  `$('.message-baron').attr("class","message-remind-success").html(".xxx.").slideDown(400); ` в  `if (data == 'yes'){
              $(this).show();` вот тут `}`

Comment: @harbor не совсем понятно, в чем проблема. Что не работает, если Вы вставляете Вашу строчку кода?

Comment: ну он не показывает сообщение которое указано в этой строке которую хочу добавить,  вот  это  мне снова выводит `$(this).show();` а `$('.message-baron').attr("class","message-remind-success").h‌​tml(".xxx.").slideDo‌​wn(400);` не хочет выводить

Comment: @harbor Вы не могли бы привести фрагмент html нужный для воспроизведения того, что происходит у Вас? Желательно в новом вопросе, а ссылку здесь мне напишите.

Comment: вот [ссылка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/628384/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0) на вопрос