# Как вывести сообщение об успешной отправке? в чем ошибка

Tags: javascript, html

Как вывести сообщение в строку `<p class="message-baron"></p>`об успешной отправке, в чем ошибка?

```
<form>
  <div>
    <p class="message-baron"></p>
    <textarea class="comment_menu"></textarea> 
    <p class="submit-kom" iid="x">Отправить</p>                                        
  </div>
</form>

$('.submit-kom').click(function() {

    var commentMenu = $(this).closest("form").find(".comment_menu");
    var comment = commentMenu.val();
    var iid = $(this).attr("iid");
    var comment_menu;

    if (comment != "") {
        comment_menu = '1';
        commentMenu.css("borderColor","#DBDBDB");
    } else {
        comment_menu = '0';
        commentMenu.css("borderColor","#FDB6B6");
    }             

    if ( comment_menu == '1') {
        $(this).hide();

                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../xxx/xxx.php",
                data: "id="+iid+"&comment="+comments,
                dataType: "html",
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {
                if (data == 'yes'){
                    $(this).show();
                    $('.message-baron').attr("class","message-remind-success").h‌​tml(".Ваше сообщение успешно отправлено.").slideDo‌​wn(400); 
                }
                }
                });  
            }         
        });
```

Comment: `this` в `success` - не то, что вы думаете

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я же Вам показал, как обеспечить правильный `this` в обработчике `success` в [Как определить нажатие одной формы из нескольких, но при этом использовать 1 функцию(общую для всех форм)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/623029) . Ошибка с `comment`/`comments` тоже перекочевала из того вопроса.

```js
$('.submit-kom').click(function() {

  var commentMenu = $(this).closest("form").find(".comment_menu");
  var comments = commentMenu.val();
  var iid = $(this).attr("iid");
  var comment_menu;

  if (comments != "") {
    comment_menu = '1';
    commentMenu.css("borderColor","#DBDBDB");
  } else {
    comment_menu = '0';
    commentMenu.css("borderColor","#FDB6B6");
  }             

  if ( comment_menu == '1') {
    $(this).hide();
    // instead of ajax - simulate asynchronous call with "bind":
    setTimeout((function(data){
        if (data == 'yes'){
          $(this).show();
          $('.message-baron').
            attr("class","message-remind-success").
            html(".Ваше сообщение успешно отправлено.").
            slideDown(400); 
        }
    }).bind(this), 1000, "yes");
    /*$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "../xxx/xxx.php",
      data: "id="+iid+"&comment="+comments,
      dataType: "html",
      cache: false,
      success: (function(data) {
        if (data == 'yes'){
          $(this).show();
          $('.message-baron').
            attr("class","message-remind-success").
            html(".Ваше сообщение успешно отправлено.").
            slideDown(400); 
        }
      }).bind(this),
      error: function() { console.log("error"); }  
     });*/
   }         
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div>
    <p class="message-baron"></p>
    <textarea class="comment_menu"></textarea> 
    <p class="submit-kom" iid="x">Отправить</p>                                        
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: спасибо большое, очень сильно помогли. Я просто окончательно не понял `this` и тд. Буду разбираться, спасибо